# Fedora - Reinstalling GMP with C++ support

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, yum, gmp

I'm trying to install a library that uses gmp and am running the ./configure on it.
So far, I've gotten past several snags, such as requiring gcc, g++, and m4 by using:

```
yum install gcc
yum install gcc-g++
yum install m4
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
checking for the GMP library version 4.1.3 or above... no
configure: error: Cannot find GMP version 4.1.3 or higher.
GMP is the GNU Multi-Precision library:
see http://www.swox.com/gmp/ for more information.
When compiling the GMP library, do not forget to enable the C++ interface:
add --enable-cxx to the configuration options.
```

As such, I tried both installing and updating gmp using yum:

```
yum install gmp
yum update gmp
```

Install tells me it's already installed and is v. 5.1.2
Updating says there's nothing to update.

I went to the gmp site and it is currently v. 6.0.0

I downloaded it and ran configure (using --enable-cxx), make, and make install.
Yet, nothing has changed.  It still says I have v. 5.1.2 and the configure for the library still says it can't find 4.1.3 and above / try enabling c++.
The gmp files (such as gmp.h) are being placed in /usr/local/lib and /include

I've been at this for hours without any progress.  I'm rather new to linux so I imagine there's something I just don't know about.

Am I not installing 6.0.0 correctly to overwrite the already installed one?
Or is there a way to reinstall the original with the c++ option?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something like `yum install gmp-devel` or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I gave it a try and it installed.  However, the same message came up with I ran the ./configure about gmp c++ not enabled.

Comment: yum install gmp-devel Worked for me when installing StrongSwan

Answer (score 2):

dnf install gmp-devel resolved this for me on rhel

Comment: Same on Fedora.

Comment: Y.o.u s.a.v.e.d m.e!

Answer (score 1):

When you manually install something, as you have, it doesn't get installed in the normal /usr/lib directory and therefore it doesn't overwrite it. This is a good thing. In general, you shouldn't mess with files installed by the package manager. (Except in the case that they are config files that are meant to be edited.)

When you install manually, it is installed to /usr/local/lib. Fortunately, GCC and other compilers don't care which directory something is installed in, they will find it (when it's in standard places like /usr/* or /usr/local/*).

Just include the C++ header and add the correct -l library flag.

Comment: I figured it was something like this.  I'm new to using ./configure, however.  
Where/how would I add the c++ header?  And where to I put the -l flag?
Would it be something like ./configure -l(file location)?

Comment: Oh crap I'm stupid. Have you installed gmp-devel? If not, run `sudo yum install gmp-devel` and that should be enough to fix it. I've had this problem 100 times myself, forgetting the *-devel package, and I should have thought of that first. The reason you need it is that, when you want to build a package from source (like you're doing), you need the *-devel package, because it contains the headers needed by compilers to compile programs using a given library. Get back to me on whether this fixes it and I'll edit my answer if it does.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.
Under the --help section of the ./configure for the library I was trying to install, there was actually a feature just for this:

```
--with-gmp-include=DIR
--with-gmp-lib=DIR
```

Using these, I was able to get it to install.
Thanks for the help.

I think I was too focused on trying to update the system install of gmp.